# Lower case component names (use) are no longer supported in JSX: <use>

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx

I am using a svg element in React JSX, thinking that `<use>` is valid in JSX. Is the following error correct ?

Lower case component names (use) are no longer supported in JSX: See http://fb.me/react-jsx-lower-case while parsing file

```
<svg className="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-call"></use>
</svg>
```

Using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML fixed it.

```
<svg className="icon" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:'<use xlink:href="#icon-dnd-on"></use>'}}>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

I think you're stuck using `dangerouslylSetInnerHTML` for now.

## Explanation

React only supports a subset of HTML/SVG elements and `<use />` isn't [supported yet](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#svg-elements).

With v0.12 React switched to [restricting lower-case tag names to only HTML/SVG elements](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#jsx-lower-case-convention), but as you've encountered this fails for elements that aren't on their whitelist. FB recommends [opening an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new) for valid tags they don't yet support.

You can use `{React.createElement('use')}` to force React to render the `<use />` tag but it still won't allow you set the `xlink:href` attribute since React doesn't support unknown DOM properties (see the [open issue on the topic](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140)). In the previous issue some suggest using `this.getDOMNode().setAttribute` in `componentDidMount` to set any non-standard attributes, but depending on your use case this may very well be even more inconvenient than the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` option.